# Handlebars linkTo renders empty link

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I came accross a wierd situation, using Ember and Handlebars. I have a table of records. The user should click to any record and be redirected to the item detail - quite a usual use case.

However, Ember does not renders the link correctly. It works when I wrap only a single word or element by linkTo tag, but it does not work when I wrap whole table row.

```
{{#each item in controller.content}}
    {{#linkTo "detail" item}}
        <tr>
            this is part of the link, correctly
            <td>and this is not</td>
            <td>{{item.someInfo}}</td> <!-- this neither -->
        </tr>
    {{/linkTo}}
{{/each}}
```

How can I fix this, when I want whole `tr` to work as a link?

Comment: You should probably render the link inside the `td` and not the `tr > td` inside the link

Comment: I need whole row (`tr`, as a block element) to be in a role of a link, not only the text fields of individual `td`s.

Comment: A `linkTo` will always renders an `a` element, what you want to use here is the `action` helper.

Comment: You are right. However, why cannot the `a` element, generated by `linkTo`, contain complex element structure, such as `tr`?

Comment: @PavelS. about the type of element generated by `{{linkTo}}`, you can change that from `a` to `td` via `tagName` by doing `{{linkTo 'someRoute' someModel tagName=td}} body of td goes here {{/linkTo}}`... not exactly the best solution, since the purpose of `linkTo` is to *link...to* something, and if you replace it you'll not have the anchor behaviour (url in status bar, mouse pointer, etc).. just throwing it out there how to change the generated element's tag

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tables should only have `<tr>` fields in them, and `<tr>` fields should only have `<td>` fields in them. You're trying to add an ember tag (and an anchor) outside the table row, which shouldn't be done in a table.

If you want something done when clicking a table, rather add an action to the row. Something like the following should work.

```
<tr {{action 'details' on="click"}}>
```

`details` will, of course, be a function in the corresponding controller from where you can transition to wherever you like.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried it and it seems to work. However, I am not able to perform the transition to details of a specific item, which was clicked. How do I perform the "parametrized" transition?

Comment: have a look at [the api](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute). Let me know if anything is still unclear.

Comment: Thank you, I got it now :-)